# LINQ to XML Group Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

If I have xml like:

```
<List>
  <Item>
     <Type>Type1</Type>
  </Item>
  <Item>
     <Type>Type1</Type>
  </Item>
  <Item>
     <Type>Type2</Type>
  </Item>
</List>
```

I basically want to somehow create a dictionary or list to repesent this. Here's what I have so far:

```
var grouped = (from p in _xmlDoc.Descendants("Item")
               group p by p.Element("Blah").Value into Items
               select Items);
```

How would I select it so that I create a `Dictionary<string, List<Item>>` where key is the name of the grouping and ("Type1" or "Type2").

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need random access to the items, use a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx), that's what it's there for:

```
var lookup = _xmlDoc.Descendants("Item")
    .ToLookup(e => (string)e.Element("Blah"));
```

Otherwise, if you need random access, then throw them into a dictionary:

```
var dict = _xmlDoc.Descendants("Item")
    .GroupBy(e => (string)e.Element("Blah"))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var query = (from item in document.Descendants("item")
             select new
             {
                 Key = (int)item.Value,
                 Value = (string)item.Descendants("type").Value
             }).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var grouped = (from p in _xmlDoc.Descendants("Item")
               group p by p.Element("Blah").Value into Items
               select Items).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Value);
```

Something like that, you'll have to check the correct syntax, but basically when you group by something, you have the Key and Value too, and you can use ToDictionary method to transform this into a dictionary.